# Fuction that takes imput array and outs pointer to all even numbers in array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, crash

My prof gave me this

Write a function with name getEvenNumbers. The purpose of the function is to process an input array of int typed integers and return the list of even numbers in the array. The function needs to be able to handle input arrays with arbitrary lengths. The return type of the function must be “int *", or pointer to int, namely that the function returns a pointer pointing to the memory storing the list of even numbers. No global variables are allowed. Except for these requirements, you are free to design the function. You also need to write a testing program (namely a main function) to show your design and implementation of this function are correct. Your testing program needs to do the following: first it asks the user to enter a positive integer N, then it generates a length-N array of random integers; then calls your function getEvenNumbers to get the list of even numbers in this array, and finally prints the list.

and I came up with the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int* getEvenNumber(int a[]);

int main (){
    int N;
    printf("Enter N: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int *ptr[N];
    int array[N], i;
    int *test[N];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        array[i] = (rand() % 100)+1;
        printf("%d \n", array[i]);

    }
    printf("------- \n");
    *test = getEvenNumber(array);
    for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(array); i++){
        printf("%d \n", *test[i] );
    }


    return 0;
}

int* getEvenNumber(int a[])
{
    int i,N = 0;
    int *ptr[N];
    for(i=0; i<=sizeof(a); i++)
    {

     if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
           ptr[N] = &a[i];
           printf("%d\n",*ptr[N]);
           N++;
       }
    }
     return *ptr;
}
```

However the program crashes and returns error 255 after it prints all the even numbers. I was wondering how to fix the code so it stops crashing after it prints the numbers any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: it crashes and I don't know how to fix it sorry I was not clear

Comment: Do you know on what line the program crashes? If not, you need to run it in a debugger so you can find out.

Comment: First step would be to run your program in a debugger to find out where and then why it is crashing.

Comment: `N = 0; int *ptr[N];` How big do you think the `ptr` array is going to be after those two statements?

Comment: it crashes when it runs                                                                                for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(array); i++){
        printf("%d \n", *test[i] );
} before this it is fine.

Comment: Arrays are passed as pointers.  You can't use `sizeof(a)` to get the array length in `getEvenNumber()`... you'll have to pass the length separately.

Comment: What you're doing with `ptr` doesn't make sense, either... you can't resize it by incrementing `N` after the declaration... and it doesn't make sense to make it an array of `int *` then return the value of the first element (you'll have no way of accessing the rest of the array).

Answer (score 1):

Your `getEvenNumber()` does not know the size of `int a[]`. `sizeof(a)` gives you the size of your `int*` (size of pointer is system specific, e.g. on 64-bit machine it is 8).
In order to fix your design you have to pass the size of the array somehow to your getEvenNumber() function.
Try adding second parameter to it something like:

```
int* getEvenNumber(int a[], int len)
```

You then would have to modify the code like follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* getEvenNumber(int a[], int* len);

int main (){
    int N;
    printf("Enter N: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int array[N], i;
    int *test;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        array[i] = (rand() % 100)+1;
        printf("%d \n", array[i]);

    }
    printf("------- \n");
    test = getEvenNumber(array,&N);
    if(test)
    {
        for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", test[i] );
        }
        free(test);
    }

    return 0;
}

int* getEvenNumber(int a[], int *len)
{
    int i,eNum=0,j = 0;
    int *ptr=0;
    for(i=0; i<*len; i++)
    {
     if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
           eNum++;
        }
    }
    if(eNum>0)
    {
        ptr = (int*)malloc(eNum*sizeof(int));
        for(i=0;i<*len;i++)
        {
            if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
               printf("%d\n",a[i]);
               ptr[j++]=a[i];
            }
        }
        *len = eNum;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with using `sizeof()` function.
`sizeof(array)` returns the total size of the array including the number of bits reserved of `int`. Have a look at the following program:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d",sizeof(a)); \\returns 20
    printf("%d",sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])); \\returns 5
    return 0;
}
```

Hence your program is trying to access pointers out of bound of the array.